# Ignore punctuation and case when comparing two strings in Python

Tags: python, string, case

I have a two dimensional array called "beats" with a bunch of data. In the second column of the array, there is a list of words in alphabetical order.

I also have a sentence called "words" which was originally a string, which I've turned into an array.

I need to check if one of the words in "words" matches any of the words in the second column of the array "beats". If a match has been found, the program changes the matched word in the sentence "words" to "match" and then return the words in a string. This is the code I'm using:

```
i = 0
while i < len(words):
    n = 0
    while n < len(beats):
        if words[i] == beats[n][1]:
            words[i] = "match"
        n = n + 1
    i = i + 1
mystring = ' '.join(words)
return mystring
```

So if I have the sentence:

```
"Money is the last money."
```

And "money" is in the second column of the array "beats", the result would be:

```
"match is the last match."
```

But since there's a period behind "match", it doesn't consider it a match.

Is there a way to ignore punctuation when comparing the two strings? I don't want to strip the sentence of punctuation because I want the punctuation to be in tact when I return the string once my program's done replacing the matches.

Comment: Should `words = "match"` not be `words[i] = "match"`? You seem to be overwriting your `words` array with the string "match".

Comment: I typed it up wrong, that's how it was, thanks, I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new string that has the properties you want, and then compare with the new string(s).  This will strip everything but numbers, letters, and spaces while making all letters lowercase.

```
''.join([letter.lower() for letter in ' '.join(words) if letter.isalnum() or letter == ' '])
```

To strip everything but letters from a string you can do something like:

```
from string import ascii_letters
''.join([letter for letter in word if letter in ascii_letters])
```

Comment: I want to retain the existing capitalization of words and I want to keep all commas in tact, though.

Comment: For purposes of the comparison, or for the output string?  Doing a list comprehension will *not* change the values of anything (except what you assign it to).

Comment: So for example, if the sentence is "Hey, my name is, bob", the 2-D array would be ["Hey,", "my", "name", "is,", "bob"]. If the word "name" exists in the 3-D array, it wouldn't return "Hey, my match, is bob" (which is what I'd like for it to return), since "name," doesn't match "name". I want to ignore the punctuation only when comparing the strings.

Comment: In that case, you will want to use regex.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be using regex

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex:

```
import re

st="Money is the last money."

words=st.split()
beats=['money','nonsense']

for i,word in enumerate(words):
    if word=='match': continue
    for tgt in beats:
        word=re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(tgt),'match',word,flags=re.I)
        words[i]=word

print print ' '.join(words)
```

prints

```
match is the last match.
```

Comment: What does the line "if word == 'match': continue" mean, since it's not searching for the word 'match'? I'm just curious since it works, but I don't get it.

Comment: This is just a demo. You will need to adapt it to your data structure since you did not provide enough of an example of that.

Comment: The line `if word == 'match': continue` just skips over a previous match. Not necessary I suppose...

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this and for your time, I'll rewrite the code I have using regex.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only the fullstop that you are worried about, then you can add another if case to match that too. Or similar you can add custom handling if your cases are limited. or otherwise regex is the way to go.

```
  words="Money is the last money. This money is another money."
  words = words.split()
  i = 0
  while i < len(words):
    if (words[i].lower() == "money".lower()):
      words[i] = "match"
    if (words[i].lower() == "money".lower() + '.'):
      words[i] = "match."  
    i = i + 1

  mystring = ' '.join(words)
  print mystring
```

Output:

```
match is the last match. This match is another match.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, regex definitely seems to be the way to go